# HTTP GET request with URLConnection is unable to access any page

Tags: http, get, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-307

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04. This is my simple code for implementing HTTP GET method using URLConnection.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

    System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
    http.sendGet();
}

// HTTP GET request
private void sendGet() throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=flower";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

But when i compile and run this code from ubuntu terminal, the output of this code does not give the content of the page specified by the URL. Rather it gives the following output

```
Testing 1 - Send Http GET request

Sending 'GET' request to URL : http://www.google.com/search?q=flower
Response Code : 307
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>307 Temporary Redirect</title></head><body><h1>Temporary Redirect</h1><p>The document has moved <a href="https://ifwb.iitb.ac.in/index.php?add=www.google.com/search">here</a>.</p><hr><address>Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora) Server at www.google.com Port 80</address></body></html>
```

This issue holds for any URL I specify in the code. Moreover, I tried to access web content using telnet client like

> telnet www.google.com 80
>         GET /

and it gives the similar result not only for www.google.com but for every URL.
I am a student at IIT Bombay and may be it has something to do with https://ifwb.iitb.ac.in.
I also want to stick to java.net and not apache httpclient. So help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're rejected by the server due incomplete request. It's a good idea to use any sniffer like Fiddler or Wireshark to "learn by example": compare your requests and requests from particular software like browsers.

Below is an excerpt from Wireshark dump, how IE10 sends GET request to interested URL. As you can see, there are various fields that describe capabilities and expectations of your client side so queried server can return the answer in most suitable and consumable form. Consult with Google/RFC to see the meaning of each parameter passed in:

> GET /search?q=flower HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
>
> Accept-Language: en-US
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/6.0)
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Host: www.google.com
>
> DNT: 1
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Cookie: [some private info here]